# CakePHP Retrieve results from multiple tables in one model

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP version : 2.X

I have completely edited this post in order to reformulate my question to be clearer.
I'm creating a professional proposal system which contains 5 tables:

proposals.........> id - name - content - created
clients..............> id - name - content - created - proposal_id
products..........> id - name - content - created - client_id
specifications..> id - name - content - created - product_id
appendices.....> id - name - content - created - product_id

I've simplified the columns for the purpose of this example.

So the associations are the following:

proposals > HasMany  > clients
clients > BelongsTo > proposals / clients > HasMany > products
products > BelongsTo > clients / products > HasMany > specifications
products > BelongsTo > clients / products > HasMany > appendices
specifications > BelongsTo > products BelongsTo > products

Then I created 5 models with the associations above.

It would look something like this:

proposal 1
....client 1
........product 1
............specification 1
............specification 2
............specification 3
............appendice 1
............appendice 2
........product 2
............specification 4
............specification 5
............appendice 3
............appendice 4

proposal 2
....client 2
........product 3
............specification 6
............specification 7
............specification 8
............appendice 5
............appendice 6
........product 4
............specification 9
............specification 10
............appendice 7
............appendice 8

And so on...

My question is how can I get an array that looks like this and retrieve me all these information in the view index.ctp of my ProposalController.php action?

Thank a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: You should really read up on how to bake in the console. It will automate all of your relations in your models for you. This is a bit dated but still effective.. I recommend http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9B2E2E37CCB661D6 Andrew Perkins tutorials, mainly Cakephp Blog Tutorial Part 10 - Setting Up the Cake Console and Bake

Comment: Thank you LetterSticker, some of these day I will try that but at the moment I'm learning OOP and CakePHP framework so I still prefer to get my hand dirty so I know how it works. It's a bit of a headache I have to admit but I assume that once you know how it works you can totally enjoy the full power of this framework.

Comment: Does anybody could lead me in the right direction, i'm really stuck here? I can't figure out how to exploit them in order to display an array with all the informations the tables contain according to theirs linking. Thank you very much in advance, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally succeeded in building what i wanted using containable behaviour but i got a problem that i can't solve.
I'd like to retrieve a proposal id and display its attached clients, products, specifications and appendices.

To do so, i made the view action in my ProposalsController.php like this:

```
function admin_view($id){
        $this->loadModel('Client');
        // $d = $this->Proposal->find('all', array(
        $d['proposals'] = $this->Proposal->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Proposal.id' => $id),
            //'contain' => array() Tableau vide pour supprimer les liaisons
            'contain' => array('Client' => array(
                'fields' => array('id','name'),
                'Product' => array(
                    'Specification', 'fields'=>array('id','name'),
                    'Appendice', 'fields'=>array('id','name')
                    )
                ))
            ));
        $this->set($d);
        // debug($d);
    }
```

I'm retrieving the particular proposal via its id in my condition. Then I send ma query to my admin_view.ctp:

```
<h1>VIEW</h1>

<?php
// debug($proposals);
?>

<p>
    Proposition : <strong><?php echo $proposals[0]['Proposal']['name']; ?></strong>
    pour le client <strong><?php echo $proposals[0]['Client']['name']; ?></strong>
    ayant le produit <strong><?php echo $proposals[0]['Client']['Product'][0]['name']; ?></strong>
    avec la spec <strong><?php echo $proposals[0]['Client']['Product'][0]['Specification'][0]['name']; ?></strong>
    et l'annexe <strong><?php echo $proposals[0]['Client']['Product'][0]['Appendice'][0]['name']; ?></strong>
</p>
```

It works but it seems to be quite a mess especially the way i have to use [0] that seems to me non adequate. Also, if a proposal hasn't any product nor specifications or appendices, it gives me an error for those because they don't exist of course.

How could i rearrange my code to simplify my view to get it to make more sense?

Also the following is my debug($d) uncommented from the view action of my controller :

```
array(

        (int) 0 => array(
            'Proposal' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Proposal 1',
                'created' => '2013-02-15 00:00:00',
                'modified' => '2013-02-16 03:00:47',
                'due' => '2013-02-28 00:00:00',
                'content' => 'Terms and conditions of the proposal 1.'
            ),
            'Client' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Client 1',
                'Product' => array(
                    (int) 0 => array(
                        'id' => '7',
                        'name' => 'produit 1',
                        'client_id' => '1',
                        'Specification' => array(
                            (int) 0 => array(
                                'id' => '8',
                                'name' => 'spec 1 produit 1',
                                'value' => 'value 1 produit 1',
                                'product_id' => '7'
                            ),
                            (int) 1 => array(
                                'id' => '9',
                                'name' => 'spec 2 produit 1',
                                'value' => 'value 2 produit 1',
                                'product_id' => '7'
                            )
                        ),
                        'Appendice' => array(
                            (int) 0 => array(
                                'id' => '12',
                                'name' => 'Annexe 1 produit 1',
                                'content' => 'content annexe 1 produit 1',
                                'product_id' => '7'
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    (int) 1 => array(
                        'id' => '8',
                        'name' => 'produit 2',
                        'client_id' => '1',
                        'Specification' => array(
                            (int) 0 => array(
                                'id' => '10',
                                'name' => 'spec 1 produit 2',
                                'value' => 'value 1 produit 2',
                                'product_id' => '8'
                            ),
                            (int) 1 => array(
                                'id' => '11',
                                'name' => 'spec 2 produit 2',
                                'value' => 'value 2 produit 2',
                                'product_id' => '8'
                            ),
                            (int) 2 => array(
                                'id' => '12',
                                'name' => 'spec 3 produit 2',
                                'value' => 'value 3 produit 2',
                                'product_id' => '8'
                            )
                        ),
                        'Appendice' => array(
                            (int) 0 => array(
                                'id' => '13',
                                'name' => 'Annexe 1 produit 2',
                                'content' => 'content annexe 1 produit 2',
                                'product_id' => '8'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'Proposal' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Proposal 1',
                'created' => '2013-02-15 00:00:00',
                'modified' => '2013-02-16 03:00:47',
                'due' => '2013-02-28 00:00:00',
                'content' => 'Terms and conditions of the proposal 1.'
            ),
            'Client' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'name' => 'Client 2',
                'Product' => array()
            )
        )
    )
```

I get what i need meaning the proposal with id 1 but below there's another array displaying the association of my 2 models Proposal and Client that I don't need because I already have it in the very first array(int) 0.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!